# Display raspberry Pi via Gnu/Linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, hdmi

I have a raspberry Pi and I want it to display on my monitor. My monitor only supports DVI and the Pi supports only HDMI. I was wondering if there is a way I can connect my raspberry pi, via hdmi, to my pc and have it display on its screen.

Comment: What OS is the Pi running?

Comment: I see that you have not accepted an answer. Does one of the answers below, solve your problem? or do you need more help?

Answer (score 3):

Option 1) Get a cheep hdmi to dvi cable, they are electrically the same (except no sound on dvi).

Option 2) Use X11, to display windows from raspberry pi (running Raspbrian, or other X11 based Linux). Use `ssh -X` to connect to raspberry Pi.

Option 3) Use VNC, to display whole screen, or a virtual screen.

(Options 2 and 3, require a network connection between the machines.)

Comment: remember to plug th monitor in before booting the raspberry pi.

Comment: @Jasen Having to plug in monitor before boot was annoying me. This was a long time ago, so I do not remember how, but I configured static display configuration, then I could turn on display latter.

Comment: I didn't want him trying the cable and deciding it didn't work,

Answer (score 3):

You can use a HDMI to DVI adaptor. There is a cheap one [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20181120145305/https://www.amazon.co.uk/Adapter-Genuine-CPO-Branded-Product-HDMI-female-DVI-Add-Item/dp/B003X8RXGK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1510080769&sr=8-1&keywords=hdmi%20to%20dvi%20adaptor) for £2.99 on amazon.

You can also connect directly to a computer using a crossover. This is just like a standard telephone cable but has an Ethernet connector at both ends. There is a cheap one [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20181120145503/https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cable-Core-Cat5e-Ethernet-Crossover-Network/dp/B00372JXKG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1510080894&sr=8-1&keywords=crossover%20ethernet%20cable&dpID=31ZZcUDBb2L&preST=_SY300_QL70_&dpSrc=srch) you can use.

Note: Links are for example purposes only.